# What should I look for in a display meant for photo editing?

Tags: photo-editing, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor for photo processing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/monitor-for-photo-processing)

After reading answers to this question "[Why do my photos look better on an iMac](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/why-do-my-photos-look-better-on-an-imac)"
I am wondering what should I be looking for when choosing a display for my PC for editing photos.  Something that would yield the same quality as a 27" iMac.