# How to choose a good external monitor for photo editing

Tags: photo-editing, color-management, monitors

I have a 13 inch macbook pro and its about the only computer I own. I'm very much into photography these days and the small 13" screen somehow doesn't feel adequate to get a real feel of the photos. So, I want to get a monitor this purpose.

I would like to ask anyone professioanl here about what are the things I need to look for in a monitor for this specific purpose. Everything starting from which type (LCD, Plasma, LED backlight, CRT) is better to any other feature. I'd also do a little video editing.

Any example of what monitor you use is also welcome.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I look for in a monitor for photo processing?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-monitor-for-photo-processing)

Answer (score 5):

Pick a monitor with an IPS panel. Suffice it to say these monitors offer far superior viewing angles and colour performance for photographers and anyone working in visual arts, over the inferior TN panels that are more common in budget monitors.

Like you I have a 13" macbook and I recently picked up an [HP ZR24W](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/382087-382087-64283-72270-3884471-4101131.html) after a few recommendations and favourable reviews. It is fabulous, offers good colour space support, is feature-packed (USB hub, lots of rotation options etc) and most of all not as expensive as many IPS monitors (such as the Dell IPS 24" which was about 40% more again).Also 24" was a good size - large enough to see lots of photos at once in Lightroom, but not too large to be pricey and graphics-demanding. I most strongly recommend it!

Comment: The other nice thing about that monitor compared to a lot of other monitors is the aspect ratio - many monitors these days are widescreen, much wider than tall - the aspect ratio of the monitor you linked to is closer to a 4x6 in aspect which is nicer also for photo editing.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess the easiest answer would be [EIZO](http://www.eizo.com). I know a lot of graphic designers using eizo monitors because of their good color quality. Each monitor is calibrated separatly in the factory. I should note that EIZOs are more expensive than regular monitors!

They have a [pdf](http://www.eizo.com/global/products/library/manga/pdfs/Guide_to_deeper_understanding_of_digital_photography.pdf) about photography and printing which although marketing material is quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Also it really what you are trying to do. If you have a new Macbook (displayport) you could also look into the Dell U2711 which is a "cheap" 27" monitor and really helps when using Lightroom for example. (It is also an IPS Panel)