# What are the major differences that differentiates LCD with an LED display?

Tags: display, lcd

I have quite read about the LCD's and LED's and I have jumped into conclusion that LED is far better than LCD.

Am I wrong in my assumption?

If I am wrong then please let me know the benefits of LCD and if I am right I want to still go in depth about the LED's..

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: here the biggest difference is price :P

Comment: Is this really related to photography?

Comment: @Mike I'd say yes, it's related to post-processing of photos. I'd expect the answers to be mostly concerned about practical implications of the technologies and less about implementation details. See also: [What should I look for in a monitor for photo processing?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-monitor-for-photo-processing)

Comment: Displays are used for post-processing, but there's no reference to that here. If the question was edited to be more specific, that's fine, but as it is it's really not a photography question.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two types of LED displays.

1. As explained by @Pete, a normal LCD-display with LED back-light instead of fluorescent tubes / strips. This is the kind you'll find in stores today.
2. Displays with Red-Green-Blue LEDs without the "LCD" part. Sony just released TVs with this technology. It's comparable with OLEDs in that both generate the colours directly, without using "filters".

Both have benefits over "normal" LCDs, but an LED display is automatically much better than a more traditional LCD. Some LED displays use LED along the edge of the screen, and pretty much work exactly as fluorescent LCDs. Other LED displays have the LEDs scattered over the whole display surface, behind the LCD panel. This makes it possible to have different brightness for different regions of the display.

The full on (O)LED displays will allow pixels to be completely black (turned off) while the neighbour pixel can be bright "white". This will allow for a much higher dynamic range in the display.

Comment: Might also want to touch on the energy efficiency. While CCFL's are energy efficient, they are not as energy efficient or low-heat as LED's.

Answer (score 2):

An LCD display requires a back-light. An LED display is an LCD display that uses LED for generating the back-light.