# How does Dell UltraSharp U2412M perform for photo editing?

Tags: photo-editing, monitors, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I look for in a monitor for photo processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-monitor-for-photo-processing)

I'm buying a monitor which I'll be using for editing with Lightroom and Photoshop. Problem is I'm far from being an expert on the subject so I'd appreciate a few opinions. I'm looking at the [Dell UltraSharp U2412M](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dell-Ultrasharp-U2412M-Widescreen-Monitor/dp/B005LNDPPS/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top). I've read reviews and it looks like good value although it's eIPS but I'd prefer to get some comments from photographers.

I'm currently using my MacBook monitor (13" from 2008) so no doubt I'll see a huge improvement. I've seen monitors that are a lot more expensive, and not necessarily much larger, so my question is: does this Dell do a good job for my needs?

Comment: not at all. I'm asking about a specific monitor

Comment: The format of the other question is preferable as it benefits a much wider audience than just the person asking the question, and will still be relevant over a much longer time period.

Comment: Yes, but maybe OP already knows what qualities a good monitor has but does not know what monitors have these qualities. Maybe not as interesting for the future but very interesting at this moment.

Comment: @Rene while that may be true, a list of current monitors with those qualities is A) not future proof and B) up to the OP to research himself.

Comment: well that's all very clear then, thank you. @ElendilTheTall that's what I'm doing here!

Comment: On reflection: while we generally discourage general shopping questions ([background here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), this probably falls under "please review this photographic item", which [we are generally okay with](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions). I'm voting to reopen.